# Timer to countdown for 6 hours and stop when time is reached and then start again for another 6 hours when button is pressed

Tags: swift, timer, countdown, nsdatecomponents

I need a timer to countdown for 6 hours.

.It has to reset when the time is reached

.It has to be activated when a button is pressed.

.It has to continue to run while the app is both open or closed.

I have one countdown timer to a date and have another countdown timer which only works while the app is active.

How do I make a timer which counts for 6 hours?

Timer countdown to date ⬇︎

```
var timeCount: NSDate?
var timer = Timer()

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func countdown()
{
let endTime = "08-10-2020 18:00:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
timeCount = (formatter.date(from: endTime))! as NSDate

let currentDate = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let diffDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: timeCount! as Date)

let countdown = "\(diffDateComponents.hour ?? 0):\(diffDateComponents.minute ?? 0):\(diffDateComponents.second ?? 0)"

let hourS = diffDateComponents.hour!
let minuteS = diffDateComponents.minute!
let secondS = diffDateComponents.second!

print(countdown)

if countdown == "0:0:0"
{
   button.setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
   button.backgroundColor = .green
   timer.invalidate()
}
else
{
   button.setTitle("PRESS WHEN TIME RUNS OUT" + "\n\(String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hourS, minuteS, secondS))", for: .normal)
   button.backgroundColor = .red
}
}
```

Timer countdown only while app is active ⬇︎

```
var timer = Timer()
var hours = 06
var minutes = 00
var secs = 00


timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func countdown()
{
    secs = secs-1
    if (secs<0)
    {
        secs = 59
        minutes=minutes-1
        if (minutes<0)
        {
            minutes = 59
            hours = hours-1
            if (hours<0)
            {
                hours = 0
                minutes = 0
                secs = 0
                
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

var hourp: String
var minutesp: String
var secp: String
    
if(hours<10)
{
hourp = "0" + String(describing: hours)
}
else
{
hourp = String(describing: hours)
}
if(minutes<10)
{
minutesp = "0" + String(describing: minutes)
}
else
{
minutesp = String(describing: minutes)
}
if(secs<10)
{
secp = "0" + String(describing: secs)
}
else
{
secp = String(describing: secs)
}
let timing = hourp + ":" + minutesp + ":" + secp
    
print(timing)

if hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && secs == 0
{
button.setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .green
else
{
button.setTitle("PRESS WHEN TIME RUNS OUT" + "\n\(timing)" , for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .red
}

}
```

Comment: Just save locally, easiest to UserDefaults, save the timestamp when the timer starts counting, then on next app opening, compare to the actual date timestamp, and see if it is more than 6 hours, or even see how many times it counted x6 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think I've solved it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up having to do for it to work for me as intended.

Thanks to the answer from @Burak Köse for steering me in the right direction.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var timer = Timer()
var currentTime = Date()
var compareTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(-21600)


func setupButtonTitle()
{
 if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "count6") == nil
    {
        button.setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    else
    {
        button.setTitle("PRESS" + "\nIN " + "\(startTimer()))" , for: .normal)
    }
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap), for: .touchUpInside)
}


func startTimer()
{
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(sixHourCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func sixHourCountdown()
{
    let timeStarted = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "count6")
    
    let timeStart = timeStarted as! Date
    let diffComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: compareTime, to: timeStart)
    let hour = diffComponents.hour!
    let minute = diffComponents.minute!
    let second = diffComponents.second!
    let timeRemaining = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second)

    compareTime += 1
    
    if hour == 0 && minute == 0 && second == 0 || timeStart < compareTime
    {
        button.setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    else
    {
        button.setTitle("PRESS IN" + "\n\(timeRemaining)", for: .normal)
    }
}


@objc func buttonTap()
{
    if button.currentTitle != "PRESS"
    {
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute:
        {
         button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        })
    }
    if button.currentTitle == "PRESS" && button.backgroundColor == .green
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "count6")

        let otherVC = OTHERVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(otherVC, animated: true)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


setupButtonTitle()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the time and save it when pressed the button then you can take the time in viewdiload and compare them

It's like this;

First create 2 variable one for current time and other one is for compare

```
var currentTime = Date()
var compareTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(21600) //6 hours is 21600 second
```

Now we need to save the time when clicked the button;

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "time")
```

Now We need to compare these times;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var time = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "time")
        if let newTime = time as? Date {
        if let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: newTime, to: compareTime).hour {
            if difference > 6 {
              //make whatever you want if 6 hours is finish
            }
               }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted because your answer did help, doesn't work as it is for me but it did help.